# Evaluating the integral of a sine function

Tags: integration, trigonometry

[image]

I am having some trouble with part (b) and part (c) of this:

(b) I know that I have to differentiate it and I get $\cos (\frac{\pi}{x})$ and by using the definite integral I get $\cos (\pi n)-\cos (\pi (n+1))$

What I said was if n is even, it can be expressed as 2k; and if it's odd, it can be expressed as 2k+1

But then I proved that if it's even then it equates to 2k, and if it's odd, it equates to -2k.

However, the answer is only 2 and -2. How did they just omit the k?

As for part (c),

I wasn't sure how to do it. The answer key said it's $2+2+2+2....=2 \times 9=18$ 
But then from 0.1 to 1, there are odd numbers in there too, so won't there be the existence of a minus sign too? Furthermore, why won't there be more than 9 numbers from 0.1 to 1?

Thank you in advance for any advice on how to approach the question and sorry for any wrong tags or title labelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b), as you already have shown, the integral is equal to $\cos (n\pi )-\cos ((n+1)\pi )$.

We know that $\cos (m\pi )=(-1)^m$.

So, when $n$ is odd we have that $\cos (n\pi )=-1$. In this case $n+1$ is even, so $\cos ((n+1)\pi )=1$.

Therefore, when $n$ is odd, we have that $$\cos (n\pi )-\cos ((n+1)\pi )=-1-1=-2$$

When $n$ is even we have that $\cos (n\pi )=1$. In this case $n+1$ is odd, so $\cos ((n+1)\pi )=-1$.

Therefore, when $n$ is even, we have that $$\cos (n\pi )-\cos ((n+1)\pi )=1-(-1)=1+1=2$$

$$$$

As for c) yous have to look at which intervals the function $\pi x^{-2}\sin (\pi x^{-1})$ is positive and at which negative, and break the interval respectively.

Then you have to use the part b).

Comment: Thanks @Mary Star! Just another quick question, how do you know that $\cos (m\pi )=(-1)^m$?

Comment: We have that $$\cos (0)=1 , \ \cos (\pi )=-1 , \ \cos (2\pi )=1, \ \cos (3\pi )=-1, \ \cos (4\pi )=1, \ \text{ etc } $$ if you continue calculating this you will see that you always get the result $1$ for an even multiple of $\pi$ and the result $-1$ for an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: An other way to see it is using Euler's formula. Euler's formula is $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$ for $x=m\pi$ we get $$e^{im\pi }=\cos (m\pi )+i\sin (m\pi ) \Rightarrow e^{im\pi }=\cos (m\pi )$$ From Euler's identity we have that $$e^{i\pi}=-1$$ Therefore, we have that $$(e^{i\pi})^m=(-1)^m \Rightarrow e^{im\pi }=(-1)^m$$ So, we have that $$\cos (m\pi )=(-1)^m$$

Comment: Brilliant explanation, @Mary Star, I think the Euler's formula bit allowed me to understand this better. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you!! :-)